# Multiple Classes Implementing Same Service Contract

Tags: wcf

I have created a WCF service in which i have one service contract and multiple services classes implementing the same contract.
Could you please tell me what to edit in the app.config and how to host this service in console app.
I have one service contract and i implemented this contract in three *.cs files in wcf.

Thanks.

here is the App.config that i have written

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ProductService.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/ProductService/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address ="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ProductService.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
        <service name="ProductService.RegistrationService">
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:7777/Design_Time_Addresses/ProductService/RegistrationService/"/>
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ProductService.IService1">
                <identity>
                    <dns value ="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
        <service name="ProductService.ProductService">
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8888/Design_Time_Addresses/ProductService/ProductService/"/>
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ProductService.IService1">
                <identity>
                    <dns value ="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
        <service name="ProductService.CatogeryService">
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/Design_Time_Addresses/ProductService/CatogeryService/"/>
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ProductService.IService1">
                <identity>
                    <dns value ="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: You're going to have to make your question easier to answer than that. First off, why not post the code that you have which you think is relevant to the problem?

Comment: i have uploaded the config.hope it helps you to understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you have defined several service operations on the service contract? What you are trying to do is not possible, nor is it desirable.

Because a logical service is associated with exactly one service contract, you cannot add more than one service for the same contract.

You *can* add multiple service endpoints per service contract, but not on a per operation basis. You may want to do this to offer your service across two or more different transports, for example, HTTP and HTTPS.

You can consume all the operations from a single service (you have 4 services defined, so just get rid of the last three), but I don't think that is what you want to do.

To host each service operation on a separate service endpoint, you will needs to break up your service contract into multiple contracts.

This is more desirable as it reduces coupling between your endpoints and makes it much easier to understand what is going on.